# mariadb multiline regexp_replace

Tags: mariadb

I'm trying to replace multiple lines using the mariadb `regex_replace` function.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `entry` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test` (`entry`) VALUES ('LINE1\r\nLINE2\r\nLINE3\r\nLINE4\r\nLINE5');
```

This creates one entry which the following content:

```
LINE1
LINE2
LINE3
LINE4
LINE5
```

Let's say I want to replace LINE2 through LINE4 with ''. This should be the result:

```
LINE1
LINE5
```

I've tried so many different regexes, but I'm out of ideas, as none of these work (no lines are removed).

```
select regexp_replace(entry, 'LINE2.*LINE4', '') from test 
select regexp_replace(entry, 'LINE2[.\r\n]*LINE4', '') from test 
select regexp_replace(entry, 'LINE2[.\R]*LINE4', '') from test 
select regexp_replace(entry, '(*CRLF)LINE2.*LINE4', '') from test 
select regexp_replace(entry, '(*ANYCRLF)LINE2.*LINE4', '') from test
```

I've also tried selecting using `RLIKE`, but it also does not work (no entries returned):

```
select entry from test where entry RLIKE 'LINE1.*LINE4' 
select entry from test where entry RLIKE '(*ANYCRLF)LINE1.*LINE5'
```

It [should](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pcre/#multiline-matching) be possible, so I don't really know why this isn't working.

I'm using latest mariadb on debian (10.3.22).

To make sure this has nothing to do with the switch to PCRE2 in 10.5.1., I also check the [historical](https://web.archive.org/web/20171120075320/https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pcre/#multiline-matching) mariadb pcre docs, but the syntax did not change.

Comment: can you add how the end result should look like. your usuage is quite confusing. Aslo you should use lore ipsum text lines maybe it could clear also up somethings.

Comment: @nbk I've added the end result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved with the `dotall`-modifier `(?s)`:

```
 select regexp_replace(entry, '(?s)LINE2.*LINE4\r\n', '') from test
```

More modifiers can be found here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pcre/#option-setting

Comment: That looks good. You can also do this variant: `SET default_regex_flags='DOTALL'; SELECT regexp_replace(entry, 'LINE2.*LINE4\r\n', '') FROM test;`

Answer (score 0):

regexp_replace  doesn't work for that purpose.

I tried almost everyting here  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pcre/

and i test the logical regular expression

> (LINE1)(.*)(\r\nLINE5)

at https://regex101.com/

But Mariadb didn't accept it, no error simply couldn't find a match, neither with 103 mot 10.4

But for your purpose this REPLACE is enough

```
select REPLACE(entry, 'LINE2\r\nLINE3\r\nLINE4\r\n', '') from test
```

see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=add220e8df6a31d35717a8392d51ae34

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(entry, 'LINE2((.*)(\\R))*LINE4(.*)(\\R)', '') FROM test;
```